# Replace Django-CMS plugin instances with another plugin

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-cms

Excuse me, if I'm not using the right "django terminology", but I am new to django.

I am workin on a website which uses Django CMS and is not responsive. They use different plugins to layout the content. One of them is [djangocms_columns](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/) to realize multicolumns.

Those columns unfortunately are not responsive. I already brought Bootstrap to most of the site but would love to avoid having to replace the multicolumn element on every page. So my idea was one of the following and couldn't find out if it is possible at all.

#### Idea 1 - Overwrite the templates of djangocms_columns

The site currently works with `width` settings in percentage. I'd like to replace those with the `col-*`-classes of bootstrap. Is it somehow possible to overwrite the templates of a plugin?

As far as I understand, this is not a good way to go, so I would prefer the following idea.

#### Idea 2 - Replace the plugin instances with bootstrap-4 plugin instances

I found [this django cms bootstrap 4 plugins](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-bootstrap4) and looking forward to editing the website, I would prefer to replace the multicolumn plugin with this one. Is there a possibility to once replace all multicolumn instances with bootstrap4-row instances and somehow "migrate" the settings and contents?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically replace one django CMS plugin with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142424/programmatically-replace-one-django-cms-plugin-with-another)

Comment: @Ridim That looks promissing. I didn't look further into this problem anymore, because we decided to not migrate those pages at all 